# Group a coded text record

Tags: regex, regex-group

I've a text string that represents a database record, as in this example:

```
V1@2A56C6D1SPINCOgiorgio§]2[4
```

where every field is coded with a symbol from @ to z
and the value of each field is numeric or a string that ends with a special char §.
I've wrote a reg exp to group each field with his value:

```
([@-z])(-?\d+|.*§)
```

This expression work very well, as seen from the image below
[image]

But I found some records where the value of the 'S' field starts with a number, so my reg exp fails to match the whole substring for the S field.
see the other image below:
[image]

The correct match would be (S, 34PINCOgiorgio§)

The question is:

there is a way to match correctly the groups as I need?

The record here is an example, the real records have six more field of type 'char' like the 'S' field.

Comment: Try [`([@-z])(-?\d+(?:(?:(?![@-z]-?\d+).)*§)?)`](https://regex101.com/r/GfvfzN/1).

Comment: Thank's for answer. I've tried it on regex site, and It not work well if I remove the 34 of the S field: this field is joined with the D field

Comment: Does that mean you can have any number inside the string or should the number be unconditionnaly at front ?

Comment: Based on the constraints you gave, both ways would be correct (as would many other ways). You'll need to clarify why the latter is considered correct. Why would `D1SPINCOgiorgio§` be 2 matches but `S34PINCOgiorgio§` must be 1?

Comment: Then what is the rule? Why not `D1SPINCOgiorgio§`  should be the match? How do you know `S` is a separate field?

Comment: There is a simple rule for the fields of record line :
- a field is indicated by one char between @ and z, not only by alphabetic but also [, ], / etc
- the value of a field is numeric unless there is a terminal char like '§' in that case the field become char type.

So every char followed by a number is a field with his value, but if there is the special char §, all between field name (like S) and the special char is the value: every alphanumeric symbols .
So is valid SPINCOgiorgio§ and also SPI546giorgio§ and also S56PINCOgiorgio§